# GFCI AF breaker not tripping with outlet tester

Tags: electrical, gfci

I have a Eaton CHFN120A1CS which feeds a couple of outlets on our kitchen counter.  The combo breaker tests fine at the panel, but when I use a GFCI circuit tester on the kitchen outlet, it does not trip the breaker.  I have a different model combo breaker on the other kitchen circuit and it tests fine both at the panel and with the GFCI tester at the outlet.  So I replaced the Eaton CHFN120A1CS combo breaker (with same) and still the same problem. The wiring seems fine, so not sure if the breakers are defective or what.

Comment: What model is the other breaker? Does "I replaced the Eaton CHFN120A1CS combo breaker (with same)" mean you replaced the Eaton with the same model Eaton, or did you replace the Eaton with the unknown other model? Also, does your main panel allow the Eatons?

Comment: Does a three light tester show ground OK?

Comment: Eaton combo breaker is CH type for Cutler Hammer CH panels; which it is.

Comment: Three light tester shows outlet wired correctly with ground.

Comment: A bootleg (incorrect neutral as ground) will do that. 3 light testers are fine if you understand what they are doing, and also what they can't do.

Answer (score 2):

**Usually** when a GFCI tester won't trip at an outlet, the outlet has a bad/missing (or worse, bootlegged to neutral) ground connection.